# Android Getting Runtime Error While Starting App

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, runtime-error

I'm trying to launch my app but i'm getting runtime error all the time.
Definition of the program is: App starts when user clicks button , button will be invisible and count down starts after countdown finish Menu.java will open.

Here is my code below:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    TextView countDown;
    int counter;
    Intent menuIntent;
    Button appStartButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        menuIntent = new Intent("com.example.project_21.MENU");
        counter = 5;
        countDown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countDown);
        appStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.appStartButton);
        appStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                while (counter != 0) {
                    sleep(1000);
                    counter--;
                    countDown.setText(counter + " seconds");
                }
                startActivity(menuIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void sleep(long mill) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(mill);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.project_21"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.project_21.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.project_21.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.project_21.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/android2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startsInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countDown"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/countDown"
        android:textSize="45sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/appStartButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/appStartButton"
        android:textSize="35sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**ERROR LOG**
[image]

Comment: What is the error? Post the stacktrace

Comment: @Archie.bpgc i added picture of error log

Comment: The class where your error is, is not included here (it is Menu.java)

Comment: @neat159 : Please don't post screenshots of logcat - theyre difficult to read and interpret. Copy and paste the logcat data into a code block instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states that you are making a call to system services, before they are available.  This is because you are calling them in the onCreate() method.  Move the calls you are making in your Menu.java class (not included here, so can't tell you exactly which calls you are making) to another lifecycle method - onCreateView() is probably best for an Activity (onAttach() is a good one for Fragments).

Comment: I'm new to Android programming, so I'm not in a place to argue too much, but ... I don't see `onCreate()` on the stack, and it looks like something is being called from a _constructor_ (`Menu.<init>`) ...

Comment: I am confident this is your issue, and think you probably need to understand a little more about Android Activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.  Keep in mind that method won't necessarily exist, until you create it (since you will be overriding something in the base class).  Bottom line, move the call to your services to a different method.